# Refactoring big JSON multiple calls

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring

I am writing java/spring webapp in which every user can have its own word list. Every time when user adds/removes a word then there is a ajax call which sends a JSON with this word to add/delete and when server side is done then there is returned current word list in JSON object to jQuery.

Everything is working ok. For small JSON word list adding and removing is very fast but when word list is getting bigger then ajax calls becomes slower. And adding/removing calls will be very frequent.

Example of JSON word list [polish words]:

```
 [{"word":"abrys","wordId":646},{"word":"acpan","wordId":647},
 {"word":"akrania","wordId":457},{"word":"akwawita","wordId":648},
 {"word":"amalgamat","wordId":399},{"word":"amurski","wordId":465},
 {"word":"amurskie","wordId":1030},{"word":"ananke","wordId":649},
 {"word":"androlog","wordId":650}]
```

jQuery [more or less]:

```
$("#add_word_submit").live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var word = $('#add_word').serializeObject();
    $.postJSON("word.html", word, function(words) {
        showDividedAccountWords(words);     
    });
});

$(".delete_button").live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(confirm(Main.confirmWordDelete)) {
        var wordId = $(this).attr("id").substring("delete_".length);
        wordName["word"] = $(this).children("img").attr("alt");
        $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: "word/" + wordId + ".html",
            success: function(words) {
                showDividedAccountWords(words);
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

Java/Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/word", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Word> addNewWord(@RequestBody Word word, Principal principal) {
    wordService.addNewWord(word, principal.getName());
    return getCurrentWords(principal.getName());
}

@RequestMapping(value="/word/{wordId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public @ResponseBody List<Word> deleteWord(@PathVariable Long wordId, Principal principal) {
    wordService.deleteWord(wordId, principal.getName());
    return getCurrentWords(principal.getName());
}

public List<Word> getCurrentWords(String username) {
    List<Word> accountWords = new ArrayList<Word>();
    accountWords.addAll(wordService.listUserWords(username));
    return accountWords;
}
```

Could you please give me some hints to refactor it? Maybe i shouldn't return a current word list every time user add/removes word?

Comment: Why are you returning the entire list from the server? Can you just add new words/Id's incrementally?

Comment: The list of word is returned from the server ordered alphabetically so that in jquery i just have to display it. And I would like to have refreshed list all the time. How can i add words incrementally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To incrementally add word objects to the list, pass the new word to the server and have it return just a single (word:wordid) object. You can then add it to the existing list and sort it as follows:

```
var words=[{"word":"abrys","wordId":646},{"word":"acpan","wordId":647},
 {"word":"akrania","wordId":457},{"word":"akwawita","wordId":648},
 {"word":"amalgamat","wordId":399},{"word":"amurski","wordId":465},
 {"word":"amurskie","wordId":1030},{"word":"ananke","wordId":649},
 { "word": "androlog", "wordId": 650}];


var result = { "word": "aklina", "wordid": "702" }; // returned by server from AJAX call
words.push(result); 

words.sort(
  function(a, b) {
    return a.word.localeCompare(b.word);
  }
 );
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I refactored my adding/removing words code according to your clues and everything is working nicely :)) In addition to this I added an index on column in word table in my postgres database. I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would have the java/spring process the information, but return only a small string to see if delay is in the transfer of data. If there is no substantial difference in java/spring processing the data, then it is either in the transfer or jquery processing. You can test that by having jQuery just send a alert to the console when the transfer is complete. If that is fast then it must be jQuery processing the longer data data.

Comment: I added alert at the beginning of the callback postjson function and it is slow. It is not showing so fast. I checked the duration of postJSON in firebug. For 456 words its 662ms and for 3 words it is 94ms

Comment: Is it close to the same time if your java returns the same sting when you process 456 words at 3 words?

Comment: alert at 3 words is much faster

Comment: Then you need to try and figure out a way to speed up your java process. I don't know java, so I can't help there.